# Recur won't compile in perfectly tail-recursive function

Tags: recursion, clojure, lisp

```
(defn matrix-diagonals-odd-p
  ([matrix] (matrix-diagonals-odd-p matrix 0))
  ([matrix offset]
     (let [len (alength matrix)]
       (if (> (+ (bit-shift-right len 1) (bit-and len 1)) offset)
         (if (= (+ (bit-and (get (get matrix offset) offset) 1)
                   (bit-and (get (get matrix (- len 1 offset)) (- len 1 offset)) 1)
                   (bit-and (get (get matrix offset) (- len 1 offset)) 1)
                   (bit-and (get (get matrix (- len 1 offset)) offset) 1)) 4)
         (recur matrix (inc offset))
         false) true))))
```

And I'm getting `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can only recur from tail position` But this *is* tail position. Why / what gives?

Comment: This looks ok to me. Could you double check this is actually what you're testing? Could the error actually be in alength?

Comment: Ok, the best way to develop Clojure is interactively, with a REPL, rather than compiling and running Java. I suspect you were just accidentally running an old version.

Answer (score 1):

This is works for me with Clojure 1.3 and 1.4. Maybe there is other functions in the same namespace that causing trouble?